# The React Router v6 Outlet seems to Reset all Session Data

Tags: reactjs, react-router, state

Here's the core part of my `App.tsx` file:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.app}>
      <Store>
        <Header />
        <SessionMgr />        
        <Banner />
        <Routing />
        <Footer />
      </Store>
    </div>
  );
};
```

`<Routing />` contains all of the routes in my app.  Here's an abridged version of it:

```
const Routing = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
      <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
      <Route path='/signin' element={<SignIn />} />

      <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
        <Route path='/settings' element={<Settings />} />
      </Route>

      <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

Today, after doing some research, I implemented `ProtectedRoutes`:

```
const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  const sessionContainer = Session.useContainer();
  const isAuthenticated = sessionContainer.isLoggedIn();
  console.log(isAuthenticated, sessionContainer.state.user);
  return (isAuthenticated ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to='/signin' />);
};
```

I believe I've done this correctly, using `<Outlet />`.  However, when the user is logged in, and thus `isAuthenticated = true`, `Outlet` clears all of my session data.  In other words, rather than redirecting to the `Settings` component, instead the session data is cleared and the user is redirected to `SignIn`.  This is the same thing that would happen if I refreshed the app in the browser.

Elsewhere in the app, navigating from one page to another, such clearing of the session data does not happen.  Given that `<Store>...</Store>` is wrapping everything else, how can the use of `Outlet` be clearing the contents of the global store?

More importantly, might anyone have any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: I doubt that `react-router-dom` or the `Outlet` have anything at all to do with any sessions. How are you effecting the navigation after authenticating? Can you include all relevant code you are working with as part of your [mcve], i.e. the `Session` code and login/authentication logic, etc?

Comment: Shouldn't you pass the path to this route `<Route element={<ProtectedRoutes`

Comment: @monim The `path` prop is optional. Layout routes don't need to have a specified path.

Comment: @DrewReese OMG your comment saved me!  But indirectly.  Let me answer my own question so it's more visible to everyone.  But full credit to you!!!

Comment: Were you using something like `window.location = ....` instead of using `navigate(...., { replace: true })` to redirect back after authenticating?

Answer (score 1):

@Drew Reese's comment made me think in a more out-of-the-box manner and it lead to solving the problem.  As Drew indicated was likely the case, the `Outlet` was not the culprit.

Here's how I was testing this new `ProtectedRoutes.tsx` wrapper component:

1. Ensure user is logged out. Manually try to go to `http://localhost:3000/settings` and ensure one can't; redirection to `SignIn` occurs.  Great so far.
2. Login.  Go to test page I was using to test this.
3. I have a custom `Button` component I've built.  I was testing with this code: `<Button type={ButtonType.Link} text="Go to Settings page" url='/settings' />`
   It ultimately renders this code: `<a href={url} className={styles.link} onClick={onClick}>{text}</a>`
4. The bug is there ^^^.  I realized this when I noticed that there was a longer delay than simply changing pages in an SPA should take.  This made me reflect back on the fact that many event handlers will cause the same thing to occur if `event?.preventDefault();` is not included.  Add it in and all works fine.
5. So I commented out that Button code and instead used this flavor instead: `<Button type={ButtonType.Link} text="Go to Settings page" onClick={() => navigate('/settings')} />`.  Everything worked perfectly!

Thank you again, @Drew Reese for your help.  Not only did it solve the bug I was posting about but I also realize that the `a href={url}` version of my Button component does not work properly!  I'm going to try modifying it but with a `target='_blank'` property, which should allow it to work for external links.